# Highcharts X-Axis labels as Text

Tags: javascript, highcharts

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/KMsDq/#&togetherjs=efTovzjOFE), with out changing the series data, Is it possible to show x-axis labels as text i.e. `{"apple","orange","mango"}` instead of decimals i.e `{0,1,2}` with out separating labels from JSON and providing it to Categories.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
        },
        xAxis: {

            labels: {
                enabled: true
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [["apple",29.9], ["orange",71.5], ["mango",106.4]]        
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $(function () {

var seriesData = [["apple",29.9], ["orange",71.5], ["mango",106.4]];     
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
    },
    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 1,
        labels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function() { return seriesData[this.value][0];},
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: seriesData     
     }]
  });
});
```

SEE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UPmsm/)

Comment: Thanks @Nitish Kumar. Your answer really helped me. FYI if you're using drilldown charts and your data looks like this: var chartTransactionList = [{'drillDown':'Diverse','name':'Diverse','y':135.9},{'drillDown':'Health','name':'Health','y':10142.4}] then you can set the xAxis values with xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function() {
                        return chartTransactionList[this.value].name;
                    }
                }
            }  - note you get the name of the object attribute from after getting the element using this.value

Answer (score 7):

You can use `catgories` in `xAxis`

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ["apple", "orange", "mango"],
}
```

I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lq6me/1/

If you don't want to use categories you can go for

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need to do it manually the better solution is just pass **type: 'category'** in xAxis block. Look below snippet

```
xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
          rotation: -45,
          style: {
                  fontSize: '13px',
                  fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
               },
          }
     }
```

Comment: i would think the best answer so far, the series is the only place to put in data